# Make 1st letter the last letter in the word

Tags: c

I need help rotating words so they output with the 1st letter at the end.
I have a file called flip.txt

```
backpack
carpet
rotate
```

and i want to be able to enter ./RotateWord < flip.txt (in terminal) and it should output

```
ackpackb
arpetc
otater
```

I was able to get it to output the words with the 1st letter missing . How to i make it output the 1st letter at the end?

Heres my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 81

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char string[BUFFER_SIZE];

while(fgets(string, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin) > 0) {
  int numChars = 0;
  while(string[numChars] && string[numChars] != '\n')
     ++numChars;

  int i;
   for(i = 1; i < numChars; ++i){

       if (string[i] == '\n'){
           putchar(string[0]);
           putchar('\n');
       }
       else {
           putchar(string[i]);
       }
   }

   putchar('\n');

  fflush(stdout);
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to actually construct the rotated string in memory, or would it suffice to simply print it out?  If you just want to print it, then you can do `printf("%s%c\n", str+1, str[0]);`  You don't need any more than that.

Comment: You just want to print it? or change the content of the variable?

Comment: @coderredoc   I just need to print it out.

Comment: @TomKarzes I just need to print it out. Why didnt my code work for puttung the letter at the end?

Comment: @NotHungry2Phil It didn't work because you never see the `\n` character inside the loop.  `numChars` counts the number of characters *before* the newline.  The loop exits before you actually reach it.  You could either move the final part to after the end of the loop, or get rid of `numChars` and just loop until you encounter the newline, then print the first character and exit the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strcspn`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.3) to get rid of the `\n`.

```
string[strcspn(string,"\n")]=0;
```

If you want to print the string in that way - do this two line. (You can merge it in one line too).

```
printf("%s",string+1);
printf("%c\n",string[0]);
```

The code will be

```
while(fgets(string, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
  string[strcspn(string,"\n")]=0;
  printf("%s%c\n",string+1,string[0]);
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

#### Why your code didn't work?

The thing is as per your code the `if` block is *never* executed. So you will never get the first character printed. The previous while `loop` simply increments the variable as long as it doesn't meet the `\n`. Then in the next loop you iterate over them **`< numChars`** and then expect to see the `\n`, which won't be the case now.

#### Changing your code this would work

```
while(fgets(string, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {

   for(int i = 1; string[i]; ++i){
       if (string[i] == '\n'){
           putchar(string[0]);
           putchar('\n');
       }
       else {
           putchar(string[i]);
       }
   }
   fflush(stdout);
}
```

Earlier you were putting `\n` after every character that you print. It should be only after the last character.

#### Note:

[`fgets`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2) returns `char*` - in case of error it returns `NULL`. So to check if `fgets` is successful or not you should do a null check.

Answer (score 1):

It it possible that you're not counting the final '\n' character when you

```
while(string[numChars] && string[numChars] != '\n')
 ++numChars;
```

?

If so, you never hit

```
      if (string[i] == '\n'){
       putchar(string[0]);
       putchar('\n');
   }
```

because your loop stops one early.

Comment: How would i count the last '\n'?

Comment: You could initialize `numChars` to 1 rather than 0.  e.g. to count the one '\n' character.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop run till

```
for(i=1,i<=numChars,i++)
```

This is because the if statement does not get executed as the index does not reach the newline character.
Thus the complete code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 81

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char string[BUFFER_SIZE];

while(fgets(string, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin) > 0) {
  int numChars = 0;
  while(string[numChars] && string[numChars] != '\n')
     ++numChars;

  int i;
   for(i = 1; i <= numChars; ++i){

       if (string[i] == '\n'){
       putchar(string[0]);
       putchar('\n');
       }
       else {
       putchar(string[i]);
       }
   }

   //putchar('\n');

  fflush(stdout);
}



return 0;
}
```

Also there is no need of extra

```
putchar('\n');
```